# php structure with foreach into if

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach, break

i need create a structure where after check (1)if array is not empty, i (2)check the first value in array is bigger of my_value, if is not then check second value of array and so on.
when the (2) is true then run my instruction and after i need exit to loop and go to the end of the script.

If after check all value in my array (2) is never true then i need return to the 'else'  of (1)

'end of script' is the same for all and contain variables changed depending of the loop

I tryed with  break and goto but not working .

what is the correct structure for this.

this structure is correct?

```
$myvalue='value';
cart_mem_rest = array('value1','value2','value3','value4');
if( sizeof( $cart_mem_rest) != 0 ){  //condition 1           
    foreach($cart_mem_rest as $kmem => $vmem_rest){ 
        if ($vmem_rest > $myvalue){ 
            //condition 2 : if first array value is bigger of $myvalue 
            //run my instruction and go to end script, if not then check 
            //other value , and other value .....
            my instruction
            Break;//go to end script
        }
    }
}else{ 

    //here if conditions 1 or 2 are not verificated
    if(condition is true ){
         
        my instruction
    }else{
        my instruction         
    }
}
//end script
echo ' end script';
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: You cannot drop from an IF into an ELSE, its one or the other, you are going to have to rethink the logic

Comment: something like [this](https://3v4l.org/XWKtG) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be easier to set a variable to hold the result if the comparison succeeded inside the foreach.

In the foreach you can do the comparison `if ($vmem_rest > $myvalue)` and when that is true set for example a variable `$found = true` and break out of the loop.

Then you don't have to check if the array is not empty, and start with the foreach. If the array is empty, there is nothing for the foreach to process.

Now we can check if there was a match in the loop checking the value of `$found`

```
$myvalue = 'value';
$cart_mem_rest = array('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4');
$found = false;

foreach ($cart_mem_rest as $kmem => $vmem_rest) {
    if ($vmem_rest > $myvalue) {
        // my instruction
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!$found) {
    // my instruction
} else {
    // my instruction
}

//end script
echo PHP_EOL . 'end script';
```

Comment: thank you, your structure was helpful. I must test again, but i think that this solution can solve my problem. I'm very grateful.